# delete/update database partially for current year records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, ssis-2012

I have  sql server database which extracts data from a operational sql server database tables and tailor it into three tables on a separate database called Reporting Database. This reporting database holds data of student results for each academic year and each unit/module.

I have set-up a job which extract this data everyday from the source operational system.

I have encountered a problem where I extracted data for a student 2 weeks ago and he had some referrals exams results which have now been cleared/deleted in the source database but they are still appearing in the other reporting database.

I need to set up a job so that I can delete only current year data form this database everyday and load it into the reporting database. I do not need to update or reload previous years data as they would not change.

In short I just need to replicate what is on source database should be on the reporting database only for the current year.

Could you please advise what would be the best approach to achieve this in terms of performance.